# LWJGL All functions unsupported

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl

I am working on a project in LWJGL, and the OpenGL setup works on 2.0, but whenever I try to render on LWJGL 3.0, it returns `Function is not supported`.

The methods that have returned this error:

1. `glColor3f();`
2. `glVertex3f();`
3. `glColorPointer();`
4. `glVertexPointer();`
5. `glBegin();`
6. `glEnd();`

Our project setup is fine, and the window shows without these methods, but whenever we use them, LWJGL spits out that error. We need help and quick, so if you know why this is happening, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this: [Why a new version](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/1.2.-Why-a-new-version) These version(I mean 2.x and 3.x) have not backward compatibillity. Also there is some major changes to API between these version. So you can not just change library.

Comment: Thank you! I did more research on how I can fix this.