# LWJGL 3 unsupported function

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

we are trying to draw simple square using LWJGL 3. On one computer it works fine but on my PC it throws an error.

My draw looks like this.

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
{
     glVertex2f(0.02f, 0.02f);
     glVertex2f(0.1f, 0.1f);
     glVertex2f(0.02f, 0.1f);
     glVertex2f(0.1f, 0.02f);
}
glEnd();
```

It doesn't work also when I, for example, want to draw a simple line.

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
{
    glVertex2f(10, 10);
    glVertex2f(20, 20);
}
glEnd();
```

Every time it throws an exception from this function.

```
public static long checkFunctionAddress(long pointer) {
    if(pointer == 0L) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Function is not supported");
    } else {
        return pointer;
    }
}
```

Error looks like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Function is not supported
    at org.lwjgl.system.Checks.checkFunctionAddress(Checks.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glBegin(GL11.java:1619)
    at Main.loop(Main.java:105)
    at Main.run(Main.java:26)
    at Main.main(Main.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LWJGL All functions unsupported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626928/lwjgl-all-functions-unsupported)

Comment: It is not. This is the problem with driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so we have been looking for a answer for few hours and we figured out, that it was the driver problem.

I have installed a proper driver on my pc and it works fine now. You can find a link to install the driver on this page https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Downloading_OpenGL.